# Error using decorator: decorator() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, decorator

I`m reading and following **Pro Python** book, i createad this two decorators **annotation_decorator** and **typesafe** using the same code from book, but when i try to run this code i receive:

> TypeError: decorator() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

The code is the same of the book and i can't figure out why this does work, can you guys spot what is wrong? I hosted the PoC here in case you wanna test: https://repl.it/repls/GlassNotedPayware

```
import functools
import inspect
from itertools import chain


def annotation_decorator(process):
    """
    Creates a decorator that processes annotations for each argument passed
    into its target function, raising an exception if there's a problem.
    """
    @functools.wraps(process)
    def decorator(func):
        spec = inspect.getfullargspec(func)
        annotations = spec.annotations

        defaults = spec.defaults or ()
        defaults_zip = zip(spec.args[-len(defaults):], defaults)
        kwonlydefaults = spec.kwonlydefaults or {}

        for name, value in chain(defaults_zip, kwonlydefaults.items()):
            if name in annotations:
                process(value, annotations[name])

        @functools.wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            # Populate a dictionary of explicit arguments passed positionally
            explicit_args = dict(zip(spec.args, args))
            new_args = []
            new_kwargs = {}
            keyword_args = kwargs.copy()

            # Deal with explicit arguments passed positionally
            for name, arg in explicit_args:
                if name in annotations:
                    new_args.append(process(arg, annotations[name]))

            # Add all explicit arguments passed by keyword
            for name in chain(spec.args, spec.kwonlyargs):
                if name in kwargs:
                    new_kwargs[name] = process(keyword_args.pop(name),
                                               annotations[name])

            # Deal with variable positional arguments
            if spec.varargs and spec.varargs in annotations:
                annotation = annotations[spec.varargs]
                for arg in args[len(spec.args):]:
                    new_args.append(process(arg, annotation))

            # Deal with variable keyword arguments
            if spec.varkw and spec.varkw in annotations:
                annotation = annotations[spec.varkw]
                for name, arg in keyword_args.items():
                    new_kwargs[name] = process(arg, annotation)

            r = func(*new_args, **new_kwargs)

            if 'return' in annotations:
                r = process(r, annotations['return'])

            return r

        return wrapper

    return decorator


@annotation_decorator
def typesafe(value, annotation):
    """
    Verify that the function is called with the right argument types and
    that it returns a value of the right type, according to its annotations
    """
    if not isinstance(value, annotation):
        raise TypeError("Expected %s, got %s." % (annotation.__name__,
                                                  type(value).__name__))

    return value


@annotation_decorator
def coerce_arguments(value, annotation):
    return annotation(value)


@typesafe(str, str)
def combine(a, b):
    return a + b


combine('spam', 'alot')
```

Comment: `annotation_decorator` looks like it is supposed to take an argument, and it *returns* the decorator that takes `typesafe` et al. as an argument. You are basically replacing  your functions with the decorator, not the decorated function.

Comment: Thanks! Is very strange following a book example and have to figure out why things don't work! haha se my response based on your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified two things based on @chepner commentary:

Instead of using `typesafe` decorator on `combine` function i simple decorated with `annotation_decorator` passing `typesafe` as arg and also add function annotation to the variables of function.

```
@annotation_decorator(process=typesafe)
def combine(a: str, b: str):
    return a + b
```